# seeing different results ( screens ) on FF and Chrome for same code

Tags: css, media-queries

```
FF 102, Chrome 103 ( Mac 11.5.2 )
```

**FF screenshot**

[image]

**Chrome screenshot**

[image]

**GitHub Repo & URL**

[Code](https://github.com/vikramvi/Huddle-landing-page-with-curved-sections)

[Live URL](https://vikramvi.github.io/Huddle-landing-page-with-curved-sections/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell you exactly, why Chrome and firefox scale that SVG differently, but you should be able to solve the problem by instead of resizing the image, simply resizing a container for it:

```css
img{max-width: 100%;}

.grow-together-component__main{display:flex; flex-direction: row-reverse; align-items: center;}
.image-container{flex:0 1 50%}
```

```html
<article class="grow-together-component__main">
  <figure class="image-container">
    <img src="https://vikramvi.github.io/Huddle-landing-page-with-curved-sections/images/illustration-grow-together.svg">
  </figure>
  <section>
    <h2>Grow Together</h2>
    <p>
      Generate meaningful discussions with your audience and build a strong, loyal community.
      Think of the insightful conversations you miss out on with a feedback form.
    </p>
  </section>
</article>
```

This shoul lead to the exact same outcome in both browsers.

Comment: vielen danke for timely help, can you please explain what does .image-container{flex:0 1 50%} do and why is it better than .grow-together-component__main > figure {
    width: 90%;
  }

Comment: Is it good practice to put img inside a container always ? In case you've list of good practices wrt HTML and CSS; kindly share

Comment: The flex attribute is a shorthand notation for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis and controls the dyamic sizing of flex-children in flex-containers.

You can find a perfect overview at CSSTricks:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

As for why it is better than width: as <figure> in this case is a flex-child, i'd control it's size by the flex-attributes, which holds the opportunity to resize the image in relationship with other content.

You don't always need a container for images, in case of the sizing of SVG in different browsers, it helps resolving your issue